# Vert.x: Is there an working Example for an Vert.x FTP Client in Java?

Tags: java, ftp, client, vert.x

I want to program a FTP Client with Vert.x in Java - I found only examples for FTPClients in JavaScript. Is there any working example for programmed example in Java?

Comment: There might be. Stack Overflow, however, is not the place to make requests for them. Please read the help center to understand what is appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:
vertx-ftp-client is a simple limited async ftp client which works with vert.x
https://github.com/bckfnn/vertx-ftp-client